# Margin for bottom border

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can only add margin to the border ?

Only border should have margin not the text.
I am trying to move border not the text field. Border need to be shrinked/moved not text.

CSS :

```
 .margin-check {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7da;
          margin-left : 15px;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="margin-check">
Something I am typing for checking the border margin
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/c91xhz5e/

Comment: I am trying to move border not text field

Comment: Are you trying to say to move the border down from the text ?

Comment: lets say a content : abcdef  (not content inside a div be anything left align content and right align content) I want the border under only some particular content.not the whole text content by giving margin to the border.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use pseudo-element and then you can change size of border

```css
.margin-check {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.margin-check:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7da;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-check">
  Something I am typing for checking the border margin
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want to change size of border but just move it to right then you can just do this https://jsfiddle.net/c91xhz5e/2/

Comment: Safari browser has issue with this type of styling.

Comment: Sorry added :   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);

Answer (score 5):

In general the margin is from the content which in this case is your text. You have to use box sizing property to set the margin from you border.

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
```

This way the margin for all your elements will be from the border box and not the content box

Comment: This is what I wanted, Can you give me an example for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

In your case, where you have no borders left and right, you can simply adjust the line-height.

```
.margin-check {
   line-height:2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-indent`.

```css
.margin-check {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7da;
  margin-left : 15px;
  text-indent: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin-check">
Something I am typing for checking the border margin
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the OP wants the border to receive the _margin_ and **nothing else**