# Add margin to the border-bottom of active nav- link without affecting the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have been working on my `Bootstrap Nav` and kind of worked it out, but somehow struggling with this thing which to make the bottom border of the active link to take up the width of the text, not the container it is in. So for this came up with this idea to add some margin to the border-bottom of the active link. 
After numerous efforts, all I'm getting is the messed up UI. I need your help guys, would be great to learn something today.

**CODE**

Trying to add the code snippet but the Bootstrap nav is not working fine.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">    
  </head>
  <body>

     <!-- Just an image -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
       <div class="container">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home" style="border-bottom: none">HOME</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
         <div class="pt-lg-0 pt-3 collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
         <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-1">SECOND PAGE</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-2">THIRD PAGE</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="testimonial home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 350px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>

   <section class="testimonial home-page" id="section-1">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Second Page</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 350px"></div>
      </div>
   </section>

   <section class="testimonial home-page" id="section-2">
     <div class="container">
        <h1>Third Page</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 350px"></div>
     </div>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 999;
   display: block;
   padding: 20px !important;
   position: fixed!important;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
 }

 .navbar-nav a {line-height: normal}
 .home-page H1 {padding-top: 219px;color: #616161}
 .active {color: grey!important; border-bottom: 5px solid #8ABE25}
```

**JAVASCRIPT FOR ACTIVE LINK**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.navbar div a').click(function(event){
    //remove all pre-existing active classes
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    //add the active class to the link we clicked
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

What I have tried from this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36552554/8462903) is this :

```
.active { 
  position: fixed!important;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7da;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Messed up my UI. Also tried `box-sizing: border-box` but didn't work out in my case.

**RESULT** I want is like this :

[image: Design to be achieved]

This is my JsFiddle link : [JsFiddle Result](https://jsfiddle.net/a2baw6nt/)
If the nav bar doesn't open up kindly expand the result so that you can see the other option, don't know why the JsFiddle is behaving weird. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.navbar div a').click(function(event){
        //remove all pre-existing active classes
        $('.active').removeClass('active');

        //add the active class to the link we clicked
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px !important;
  position: fixed!important;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
}

.navbar-nav a {line-height: normal}
.home-page H1 {padding-top: 219px;color: #616161}
.active span {color: grey!important; position: relative; display: inline-block;}

.active span:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-4px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #8ABE25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">    
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!-- Just an image -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home" style="border-bottom: none">
          HOME
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="pt-lg-0 pt-3 collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-1"><span>SECOND PAGE INFORMATION</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-2"><span>THIRD PAGE</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-2"><span>FOURTH PAGE</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-2"><span>FIFTH PAGE</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#section-2"><span>SIXTH PAGE</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section class="testimonial home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 350px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="testimonial home-page" id="section-1">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Second Page</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 350px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="testimonial home-page" id="section-2">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Third Page</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 350px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

wrap your text with `span` and giving the following style.

```
.active span {color: grey!important; position: relative; display: inline-block;}

.active span:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-4px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #8ABE25;
}
```

Comment: The link is not workable. Please provide the active link. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but there is one problem I have a single text which in two lines and this is actually highlighting the two lines rather than highlighting the bottom only. I hope you understand my point. Can you take look at this now : https://jsfiddle.net/a2baw6nt/2/

Comment: Can you explain me with fiddle

Comment: Yep, I have given you a link on my above comment, just take a look at that. I hope it'd be helpful to you. Again I'm giving out the link : https://jsfiddle.net/a2baw6nt/2/

Comment: Ok look into it

Comment: I have added the **result** in my question, which I'd like to have. Since we are close to that but this particular thing needs to be handled. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169838/discussion-between-patelarpan-and-alok-kumar-verma).

Comment: Hey, I have actually used your idea and it is working however the `active span:after` taking up the `<a>` width not the span's when become active. Could you help me with this please? See for yourself : https://jsfiddle.net/a2baw6nt/5/

Comment: apply `display: inline` to span. that is only way

Comment: I have done that, but now it is working like before like using the bottom text's width. Used the `display: inline` in place `inline-block` to  `.active span`, didn't work out the way we wanted. But thanks for the suggestion. If you have any other suggestions do tell me thanks. :)